# I need to update a tag <abc><\abc> with variables from another file. Output should be an xml file with all those values comma separated within abc tag

Tags: awk, sed, xml

I need help updating an xml file, `file1.xml` which has a tag name `<abc> <\abc>`.

The `file2.txt` has numbers fixed length numbers (1 number in each row):

```
1234
5678
1435
```

I need output to a newfile.xml:

```
<abc>1234,5678,1435<\abc>
```

any `awk`,`sed` option please?

Thanks

Comment: it is unclear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: is this school work?

Comment: XML closing tags use `/`, not `\ `, by the way. And  `sed` and alike are not capable of parsing XML – it's not a regular language, but a complicated beast. So, don't try to write a parser on your own.

Comment: @jsotola yes school project, i am in kinder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two parts to this question, which use different tools

1. Join lines of `file2.txt` together with commas

   ```
   paste -s -d',' file2.txt
   1234,5678,1435
   ```
2. Insert a value into an XML file (actually, update the empty one). This required me to fix your not-XML into XML:

   ```
   cat file1.xml
   <abc> </abc>

   xmlstarlet edit --update '//abc' --value 'test' file1.xml
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <abc>test</abc>
   ```

   Once you are sure the output is what you expect you can tell `xmlstarlet` to update the file in-place by using `edit --inplace`.

Putting these together,

```
data=$(paste -s -d',' file2.txt)
xmlstarlet edit --inplace --update '//abc' --value "$data" file1.xml

cat file1.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<abc>1234,5678,1435</abc>
```

Comment: Thank you so much roaima for your help, the solution works on my other linux machine but i have no rights on the machine where i need this to install xmlstarlet.

Comment: Ask the administrators to install it for you. It's a standard package

Answer (score -1):

```
 perl -pne "s/\n/,/g" k.txt| sed -e "s/^/\<abc>/g" -e "s/,$//g" -e "s/$/\<\\\abc>/g"
```

output

```
<abc>1234,5678,1435<\abc>
```

Comment: *Please* pay attention to other answers when you work on answering a question. There are a couple of details which are wrong in the question, which makes your answer useless. (And again, if you’re using Perl you don’t need `sed`.)